# Select through a subquery in an aggregate query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to fetch a list of stores. I want the following columns in the result:

- address
- paid_amount
- jobs_count
- items_count

The following query gives me all of them, except `items_count`:

```
SELECT
       s.address AS address,
       COALESCE(SUM(j.paid_amount), 0) AS paid_amount,
       COUNT(j.id) AS jobs_count
FROM stores s
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs_coordinates jc ON jc.store_id = s.id
FULL OUTER JOIN jobs j ON j.id = jc.job_id
GROUP BY s.id, s.address
```

I have tried to get the amount of items that belongs to a store through jobs by adding a subselect:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job_items WHERE job_id = j.id) AS items_count
```

...it's giving me the following error:

> Column 'jobs.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What is the right way of fetching the `items_count` in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to mix different types of outer joins.  I would suggest that you just use a subquery to pre-aggregate the results:

```
SELECT s.address AS address,
       COALESCE(SUM(j.paid_amount), 0) AS paid_amount,
       COUNT(j.id) AS jobs_count,
       SUM(j.item_count) as item_count
FROM stores s LEFT JOIN
     jobs_coordinates jc
     ON jc.store_id = s.id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT j.id, COUNT(*) as item_count
      FROM jobs j LEFT JOIN
           job_items ji
           ON ji.job_id = j.id
      GROUP BY j.id
     ) j
     ON j.id = jc.job_id
GROUP BY s.id, s.address
```

Answer (score 0):

give this a go.

```
    SELECT
       s.address AS address,
       COALESCE(SUM(j.paid_amount), 0) AS paid_amount,
       SUM(jobs.items_count) AS jobs_count
FROM stores s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs_coordinates jc ON jc.store_id = s.id
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as items_count, id FROM job_items group by id) jobs ON jobs.id = jc.job_id
GROUP BY s.id, s.address
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like:

```
SELECT s.address,
       COALESCE(cnt.Paid_Amount, 0) AS paid_amount,
       jobs_count,
       jobItems
FROM stores s
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT jc.store_id,
               COUNT(DISTINCT job_id) AS jobs_count,
               SUM(PAID_AMOUNT) AS Paid_Amount,
               SUM(jobItems) AS jobItems
        FROM dbo.Jobs j
            INNER JOIN jobs_coordinates jc
                ON j.id = jc.job_id
            INNER JOIN
            (SELECT job_id, COUNT(*) AS jobItems FROM Job_Items GROUP BY Job_Id) ji
                ON ji.job_id = jc.job_id
        GROUP BY jc.store_id
    ) cnt
        ON s.id = cnt.Store_id;
```